# How to modify an existing Google Maps marker in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have a small problem.
When the user searches for an address, if it exists I zoom to the marker and then I want to give it a different color. 
I am trying to use this :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker
but can't seems to succeed.

Here I put all the markers on the map:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Test2"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"googlid"]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
  NSLog(@" objects : %@", objects);
  for (NSDictionary *dic in objects) {
    NSString *placeID = [dic valueForKey:@"googlid"];
    _placesclient = [[GMSPlacesClient alloc] init];

    [_placesclient
        lookUpPlaceID:placeID
             callback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
               if (error != nil) {
                 NSLog(@"Place Details error %@",
                       [error localizedDescription]);
                 return;
               }
               if (place != nil) {
                 GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                 marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                     place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude);
                 marker.title = place.name;
                 marker.snippet = @"Push to see feedbacks";
                 marker.map = _mapview;

               } else {
                 NSLog(@"No place details for %@", placeID);
               }
             }];
  }
```

Here I try to modify the marker:

```
 if (exist) {
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                 message:nil
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *exist =
                [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Place exist"
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:nil];


              GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition
                                           cameraWithLatitude:place.coordinate.latitude
                                           longitude:place.coordinate.longitude
                                           zoom:15];
              self.mapview.camera = camera;

              _targetMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
                                                                                       place.coordinate.latitude, place.coordinate.longitude)];
              _targetMarker.map = _mapview;

            _targetMarker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: What actually happens? Why do you create an alert but never use it?

Comment: I do use it to alert the user that the place exist . 
Then i wanna show him the marker that represents it and change his color...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
_targetMarker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker-icon"];
```

**Note: Marker must be initialised.**

Comment: if(!_targetMarker)
                  {
                      _targetMarker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                  }
                  for (_targetMarker in self.markersOnTheMap) {
                      if (_targetMarker.position.latitude == place.coordinate.latitude && _targetMarker.position.longitude == place.coordinate.longitude) {
                          _targetMarker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
                      }
                  }
wanna change it again to clear when map will move